# Prove $ G/H\cong K$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H,K \trianglelefteq G$,$H\cap K =\{ 1 \},G= \langle H\bigcup K \rangle$. Prove that $ G/H\cong K$,

$\langle H\bigcup K \rangle$ denotes the subgroup generated by $ H\bigcup K $

Comment: Is $H\cup K$ generated by elements of the form $hk$ only, or any combination of $h$'s and $k$'s?

Comment: Hint: Prove that $G = HK$.

Comment: h and k,not hk.

Comment: Hint: Two normal subgroups with trivial intersection have pairwise commuting elements, that is, $hk=kh$ (use normality and triviality of intersection to construct the commutator to prove this). Armed with this result, the rest should be easy.